# Are there any good professional associations for IT Managers/Programmers?

Tags: associations

Are there any good professional associations for IT Managers that I could join and network with other managers to share ideas and information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The IEEE Computer Society](http://www.computer.org/portal/site/ieeecs/index.jsp) and the [Association of Information Technology Professionals](http://www.aitp.org/). Michigan has a few [chapters](http://www.aitp.org/organization/chapters/chapters.jsp#Michigan) in the AITP.

Comment: When I lived in Michigan (up until a month ago) I went to the Lansing chapter meeting and didn't like it. However, the Grand Rapids group (Western Michigan chapter) was awesome, as was the Ann Arbor one. So good luck to you. :)

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Association for Computing Machinery (ACM)](http://www.acm.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Chartered IT Professional

http://www.bcs.org/server.php?show=nav.9214

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know there was a credential you could obtain for that. I was thinking more along the lines of a "social" type group, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Linked](http://www.linkedin.com/) in have groups for informal networks.

For something more serious or accredited: in Ireland there is the ICT, I'm sure there's something similar in Michigan or at the federal level in the US.  Maybe like the ACM mentioned by Paul C.